# ROS - SerializationError when writing a bagfile with custom ROS message

Tags: python, ros, bag, rosbag

I have a created a custom ros message which has the following format

```
# Header information
std_msgs/Header header

# Model
string model

# Data
uint8[] data
```

The data is a list of 4D lists reading from csv file

```
def createData(csv_file): 
     x,y,z,w = np.loadtxt(dataFile, usecols=(0,1,2,3), \ skiprows=0, delimiter="\t", unpack=True) 
     p = [] 
     for p1, p2, p3, p4 in zip(x,y,z,w): 
        pt = [p1, p2, p3, p4] 
        p.append(pt)
     header = Header()
     header.stamp = rospy.rostime.Time.from_sec(time.time())
     header.frame_id = "main_frame"
     model = "sensor"
     msg = customMessage(header, model, p)
     return msg, p

with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w') as bag:
    msg, points = createData(csv_file)
    bag.write(topic_name, msg)
bag.close()
```

where inside the `customMessage(genpy.Message)` class, I set the `msg.data` to `p`, `msg.header` to `header`, and `msg.model` to `model`
I created a random data with this message type, and I am trying to write a bag file out of this

```
bag.write(topic_name, msg)
```

However I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data2bag.py", line 306, in <module>
    bag.write(topic_name, msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 391, in write
    msg.serialize(self._buffer)
  File "data2bag.py", line 123, in serialize
    except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self)))))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 334, in _check_types
    check_type(n, t, getattr(self, n))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 256, in check_type
    check_type(field_name+"[]", base_type, v)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 212, in check_type
    raise SerializationError('field %s must be unsigned integer type'%field_name)
genpy.message.SerializationError: field data[] must be unsigned integer type
```

The `msg.data` has a type of `<type 'list'>` which is the assumed type
The writing of the bag file is successful if only the `msg.data` has a `str` type

Nevertheless, this does not make sense since it won't be working with a `str` data type

If I change the data to uint8 by: `points = np.uint8(p)`

I get this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data2bag.py", line 307, in <module>
    bag.write(topic_name, msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 391, in write
    msg.serialize(self._buffer)
  File "data2bag.py", line 123, in serialize
    except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self)))))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 334, in _check_types
    check_type(n, t, getattr(self, n))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 254, in check_type
    raise SerializationError('field %s must be a list or tuple type'%field_name)
genpy.message.SerializationError: field data must be a list or tuple type
```

Did anybody encountered such problem before?

I tried changing the data reading method

```
for p1, p2, p3, p4 in zip(x,y,z,w):
        pt = [int(p1), int(p2), int(p3), int(p4)]
        p.extend(pt)
```

However my p1, p2, p3 and p4 are float, I just did as int casting to try it. I got the same error

Comment: Can you show the code you use to assign that list to the data variable?

Comment: I think you just have a typo: `p = [p1, p2, p3, p4]` needs to be `pt`.

Comment: btw, where are you casting the text you are reading from file to integers?

Comment: sorry this is a typo in copying the post

Comment: @ChristianFritz  'pt = [float(p1), float(p2), float(p3), float(v)]' when I do it like that it is the same

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the elements you have in your list are just not of the right type. Impossible to say without seeing your code. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import rosbag
from std_msgs.msg import UInt8MultiArray
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w')

try:
    a = UInt8MultiArray()
    a.data = [1,2,3]
    bag.write('array', a)
finally:
    bag.close()
```

This works fine.

---

Update based on the code you posted.

I'm pretty sure your list contains arrays of strings, both of which is wrong. You want it to be flat and integers:

```
     p = [] 
     for p1, p2, p3, p4 in zip(x,y,z,w): 
        p.extend([int(p1), int(p2), int(p3), int(p4)])
```

Comment: can you use the UInt8MultiArray as an array of arrays? so simply append to it?
I edited my post to include the function for creating my data, you can check it

Comment: @Chrisitan Fritz: I am not writing the data directly in the bag file, however, it is a part of the custom ros message which I have, which includes data, header and model as a string value. So technically, msg.data should be a uint8[]. Using UInt8MultiArray is a direct std_msg which I don't want to use

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, but it didn't work too, I updated my post with your proposal

Comment: oh wait, you are not returning anything from `createData`

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the return statement, I am returning msg and p for sure

Comment: hm, have you printed p to see what it looks like?

Comment: the customMessage is a class of genpy.Message where it has its own md5sum and type

Comment: Shouldn't `p` just be a list of integers? Also, I assume you ran genpy to generate the customMessage from the msg definition you showed?

Comment: yes it's a list of integers, and my class definition is `class customMessage(genpy.Message):` with a `def __init__(self, *args, **kwds)`